# UIContainerView with intrinsic size placeholder values for AutoLayout doesn't receive events?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicontainerview

This is with Xcode 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o). It seems that specifying an intrinsic size placeholder values for a UIContainerView causes it not to receive events.

1. Create a standard single view application.
2. In the view, insert a UIContainerView (center it with Auto Layout)
3. Embed a simple button into the UIContainerView.
4. Run the simulator and observe that if you click on the button you can see that it responds (dims)
5. Stop the the simulator and add intrinsic size placeholders for the UIContainerView.
6. Run the simulator and observe that if you click on the button you no longer see that it responds (dims).
7. Stop the simulator and either remove intrinsic size placeholders or set them to NONE.
8. Run the simulator and observe that if you click on the button you can see that it responds again.

No warnings/errors appear in the log.

I've uploaded a video of this behavior [here](https://youtu.be/wFinyMk3hvw). Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? I'm rather new to auto-layouts so I want to check if I am doing something wrongly before filing a bug with Apple.